# How to set the navigation property for the below?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to "entity framework" and I have the following question.
Let's say I have the following two entities

```
public class Action
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ActionCode {get;set;}

    //navigation property
    public virtual DescriptionMaster ActionCodeDescription {get;set;}
}

public class DescriptionMaster
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Now you may notice I have a navigation property called "ActionCodeDescription"  in "Action" class  and the two entities(Action and DescriptionMaster) have one to one relationship .
However, for "ActionCodeDescritption" property,   I don't have any foreign key column and, instead, it should be the one which meet the following conditions.

```
DescriptionMaster.Type=="Action" and  DescriptionMaster.Code==Action.ActionCode
```

Is it possible to load the navigation property based on particular condition instead of having any foreign key?
I know, I may be able to do something like below , but if possible, I just want to achieve it by setting "data annotation" on the "ActionCodeDescription" somehow.

```
    Action _action= dbContext.Actions.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id==1);
    _action.ActionCodeDescription=dbContext.DescriptionMasters.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type=="Action" && x.Code==_action.ActionCode);
```

Comment: Why do you want this? If it is a one-to-one relationship, you should set the ID of Description master as foreign key. Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: The idea of having description master table is to store the friendly description of all kinds of entities' codes in the system. The type column identify the entity type and the 'Code' column is for the code used in the entity. And then friendly description will be retrieved based on those two. So, clearly I can not store the description master Id because entities' code can be changed depending on the user input.

Comment: I guess DataAnnotation could be possible I have done it once, as far as I remember

By using Helpers

Comment: This is not correct design, you cannot have database relations change based on content of table, you can only design model using structure.

Comment: @AkashKava , can you elaborate more, maybe as an answer rather than comment? I will not be hesitated to accept it an answer, if it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

From 'Programming Entity Framework dbContext" page 35 :
The ability to only load a subset of the content of a collection navigation property is a common request but is not currently supported by EF.

Not by eager loading and not by lazy loading.
Via explicit loading it is but that is the variant that you already know about as in the very last code snippet of you question.

Nevertheless you might want to read this :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter

Using projection it is of course possible to load only a subset of related data that is in a navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a composite key?

```
public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign composite key values
    [ForeignKey("DescriptionMaster"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DescriptionMaster"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual DescriptionMaster ActionCodeDescription { get; set; }
}

public class DescriptionMaster
{
    // - get rid of integer Id : public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean, I have to add a extra column in action table just for this?  Sorry, no, I will not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Database relations (foreign keys) are independent of values inside tables. Because no foreign key supports any conditions on any database.

Example,

```
Category
   CategoryID (Primary Key)
   CategoryName

Product
   ProductID (Primary Key)
   ProductName
   ProductCategoryID (FK to Category.CategoryID)
```

ProductCategoryID is FK for all possible values, like join, you cannot specify any conditions here.

However, in your case, you can use inheritance with one to one* relations.

```
public class DescriptionMaster{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}

public class ActionDescriptionMaster{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {get;set;} (FK to DescrptionMaster.Id)

    public int Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class Action{
    public int Id;

    [ForeignKey("ActionDescrptionMasterId")]
    public ActionDescrptionMaster {get;set;}
}
```

In Entity Framework, ActionDescrptionMaster is derived table of DescriptionMaster, in which, ActionDescrptionMaster value exists only if DescriptionMaster has value with Type = "ActionCode". Relationship between DescriptionMaster and ActionDescriptionMaster is zero or one to one.

Exmample values

```
DescriptionMaster
Id      |    Type      |
4       |    None      |
5       |    Action    |
6       |    Action    |

ActionDescriptionMaster
Id      |    Code      |  Description   |
5       |       54     |  Stop          |
6       |       45     |  Proceed       |

Action
Id      |    ActionDescriptionId  |
1       |       6                 |  
2       |       5                 |
```

Note that values for ActionDescriptionMaster only exists for 5 and 6. Also Action table does not have any Code, you can set referential integrity to only one primary key.

Now since I have limited knowledge, I am suggesting a clear way, if I know the proper requirements of why and what you want to store, I can suggest better design.

Comment: It does not seems to fulfill the requirement,  as long as I keep the foreign key to "ActionDescriptionMaster" at "Action". It means, every time "Action.ActionCode" is changed, I need to update with correct foreign key. Otherwise, it ends up linking to the wrong record.

Comment: If you notice, there is no ActionCode inside Action class, you can have only one FK reference to ActionDescriptionMaster, if your action is changing, your ActionDescriptionMaster will change. You only store reference to DescrptionMaster.id, you dont store Code inside Action table at all.